# Picasso error on first load

Tags: android, picasso

I have a ListView with an image loaded by Picasso using in my adapter `getView()`:

```
if (item.getPicture().contains("http")) {
     Picasso.with(context).load(item.getPicture()).placeholder(R.drawable.default_picture).into(holder.imageView);
}
```

Only the first cell gets an Image the other 2 show the default_picture. When I scroll all the other cells have an image. When I scroll back to the top the 2 cells that were blank now show an Image. Has anyone ever seen this? Does anyone have an idea of how I can debug?

[image]

Comment: Try to use AndroidQuery for image load from url.

Comment: I would advise against using AndroidQuery for loading images, it blocks the UI thread a lot.

Comment: I agree with that. My preference is to stay with Picasso if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some images are not loading because the URL is empty or does not contain "http".

The reason why you see empty cells becoming non-empty is that views are recycled. So you need to either call Picasso or set the default image for your `ImageView` manually in `getView()`, but you can never leave the `ImageView` untouched.

Because you only call Picasso conditionnaly without always clearing the image, then when the URL is empty or does not contain "http", your `ImageView` will still contain the previous image of the recycled cell.

So change your code like this:

```
if ((item.getPicture() != null) && item.getPicture().contains("http")) {
     Picasso.with(context).load(item.getPicture()).placeholder(R.drawable.default_picture).into(holder.imageView);
} else {
     holder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_picture);
}
```

Comment: You are 100% right I had not noticed it was displaying the wrong Image after the scroll. Many thanks!

Comment: You need to call `Picasso.with(context).cancel(holder.imageView)` in the "else" case. Otherwise Picasso is not aware that the ImageView was recycled.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I understand. In the case where I do not have a link I never call Picasso so it should not care what I am doing with that Image.

Comment: Like Jake Wharton said, you must also cancel the pending request, otherwise the image targeted for the recycled view will be set by Picasso when it arrives from the network asynchronously, overriding your default picture.